# Installing pillow with pip without error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library

I want to install pillow version 6.2.1 with python 3.5.0 in a virtual environment.
I tried to install it but after "Collecting pillow" my path appears without any error message, interrupting the installation.

I tried the same procedure outside of my virtual environment and the same happens.
Also without a specific version, just running "pip isntall pillow" gives me the same result.
Does anyone have experience with this and can tell me a potential reason?
Without an error it is really hard to understand what happens.

Comment: Can you share which installation parameters/arguments are you using as minimum working example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply running `pip install pillow` I believe it will try and install the latest version which is only supported by `pip > 19.2` and `python > 3.8`. Since you are using 3.5 you will have to use a downgraded version of pillow to use it or upgrade your pip/python version.

So try `Pillow==5.0.0` for python 3.5 or upgrade. I would recommend upgrading to at least 3.8 at this point to maintain stability with most packages.

Comment: somehow my installed pip was not compatible with my python version.
I gave up and changed to using VS Code with wsl.